# How to use Css and Bootstrap styles on same element in Next js?

Tags: css, next.js, bootstrap-5

I want to add the Bootstrap class `sticky-top` to another CSS style element. It doesn't work.

*I tried to do without Bootstrap by adding `position: sticky, top: 0` to the CSS but it doesn't work. Bootstrap `sticky-top` only works when I remove the CSS class `${styles.profile_nav_css}`

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "../styles.module.css";
export const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div className={`sticky-top ${styles.profile_nav_css} `}>
      <Link href="/profile" className="text-decoration-none">
        Dashboard
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href="/profile/add-vehicle" className="text-decoration-none">
        Add Vehicle
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href="/profile/hires" className="text-decoration-none">
        Hires
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```css
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .profile_nav_css {
    height: 10vh;
    border: 3px solid green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1500px) {
  .profile_nav_css {
    height: 100vh;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that you are trying to use the Bootstrap class sticky-top along with your custom CSS class profile_nav_css to create a sticky navigation bar. However, there are a few issues that might be causing the problem.

Incorrect order of CSS classes: In your JSX code, you have applied the sticky-top class first and then your custom class profile_nav_css. However, the order matters in CSS, and the properties of the class applied later may override the previous ones. To make sure the Bootstrap class takes precedence, you should reverse the order of classes:

```
<div className={`${styles.profile_nav_css} sticky-top`}>
```

Conflict with custom CSS: You have defined styles for the class profile_nav_css in your CSS file, which could potentially conflict with the styles of the Bootstrap sticky-top class. When using Bootstrap classes, it's better to avoid custom styles that might interfere with the intended behavior of the Bootstrap class. You can consider removing the custom styles for .profile_nav_css.
Here's the updated code snippet:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "../styles.module.css";
export const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div className={`${styles.profile_nav_css} sticky-top`}>
      <Link href="/profile" className="text-decoration-none">
        Dashboard
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href="/profile/add-vehicle" className="text-decoration-none">
        Add Vehicle
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href="/profile/hires" className="text-decoration-none">
        Hires
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

With this change, the Bootstrap sticky-top class should be applied correctly, and your navigation bar should become sticky at the top of the page as expected. Hope this will help.

Comment: Rearranging the order of the classes doesn't fix it